# Selenium Webdriver : Screenshots in Opera

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried using TakeScreenshot in java selenium webdriver to take screenshots. When I scroll by a specific amount using scrollTo(x,y) in the page , the TakeScreenshot method gives me the screenshot the first viewport and not the one that has been reached after scrolling.

I want to know if the TakeScreenshot method gives the screenshot of the first viewport or the current viewport in Opera webdriver. In chrome, it takes the screenshot of the current webdriver !

Answer (score 1):

I thing, it depends of the version of your Opera driver, but it usually takes screenshot of whole page(not sure about Opera Next). I'm using [AShot](http://github.com/yandex-qatools/ashot) utility customize screenshot taking. It works fine in Opera.